# Installing Railo on Media Temple

Tags: coldfusion, hosting, railo

I have a reseller account with Media temple. It doesn't support Railo ( http://www.getrailo.com/ ) out of the box but I really do want to use their service, but with some sites using Railo of course.

First port of call was Media temple to assist me...but they don't offer support with resellers on the DV with regards to installing software.

I also Googled and the only thing I can find is this (which looked perfect):

http://jakemauer.com/weblog/railo-on-mediatemple-dv-server/

However, it's out-dated somewhat and I simply do not posses enough technical skill to achieve it (I'm mainly a designer / front-end dev, offering reseller to my clients). One of the first things that guide requires is to get YUM going, but even that I was stuck on. The terminal threw up errors about other files it needed as 'dependencies' and I have no idea how to get that going. I found the process quite complicated. I'm not a server admin :(

I'd be happy to pay someone to do this, but would rather figure it out myself as I'm eager to learn too.

If anyone has experience doing this and can offer insight I'd appreciate it so much.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: That article you linked to isn't that out of date.  Could you post the specific step you were on when you got errors, and exactly what the errors were?

Comment: @Jake Actually it is out of date, Railo has the installer so steps 4-11 are obsolete. I would recommend to check out this wiki http://wiki.getrailo.com/wiki/Railo_Installation

Comment: @Sergii true, but I get the impression he isn't even that far along in the process, yet.

Comment: No you're right guys. I'm not even that far. Stuck at the first few hurdles if you like. I'll check that link Sergii. Thanks to you both for the replies. I'll get back to you soon with progress.

Comment: I just looked at this link: http://www.garyrgilbert.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/11/5/Installing-Railo-3-on-Linux-CentOS-Part-1 but that too is out of date from 2008. I haven't tried it yet though. The linux box is CentOS - so is there a more recent installation guide? I hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

The Railo installer should work just fine on a Media Temple VPS. Documentation on how to launch the Railo installer on a linux machine can be found here:

http://wiki.getrailo.com/wiki/Installation:InstallerDocumentation:LinLaunching

If you don't have a GUI on your server, don't worry, just SSH to your server and run the commands that are posted in the "Command-Line Install" sections.

If you have any problems with any aspect of the install process as outlined in the documentation, I'd recommend the [Railo mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/railo). The community there (like this one) is quite friendly and can walk you through almost any problems you encounter.